# Meteor: How can I get useraccounts package to write a new user doc into a remote collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using the packages `accounts-password` and `useraccounts:bootstrap` and it all works fine, meaning the sign-on form creates a new doc in the Meteor.users collection. But I don't want any collection on the client facing app, hence I do have a second app running to which I successfully connect via DDP.connect() and I can exchange all necessary docs/collections via pub/sub and calling methods on the remote app.

The only thing that doesn't work is the useraccount doc. I've used (on the client app):

```
remote.subscribe('users', Meteor.userId(), function() {
});
```

and (on the remote app):

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

even though I'm not sure if there is a pub/sub already included in the package. Still, the doc is written to the local (client) app and not to the remote app.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useraccounts:core` simply makes use of `Accounts.createUser` on the server side (see [this line](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/lib/server_methods.js#L103)) within a method called from the client-side (see [this another line](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/lib/templates_helpers/at_pwd_form.js#L209)).
So the new user object is created from the server side and not from the client (though it flows all the way down to the client thanks to the DDP and default users subscriptions...).

If you're really looking to change the defaul behaviour provided by the Meteor core `Accounts` packages (`accounts-base`, `accounts-password` in this case...) you should try to override the `Accounts.createUser` method which is were all begins...

In any case be warned that the current user is published to the client by default: see [these lines](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L699-L714)

Finally, to prevent `useraccounts:core` to use the `Accounts` API you could try to override the [AtCreateUserServer](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/lib/server_methods.js#L7) method and deal with the creation of a new user on a remote application inside there.

Answer (score 0):

Package `accounts-base` provide such functionality.

> The `accounts-base` package exports two constructors, called `AccountsClient` and `AccountsServer`, which are used to create the `Accounts` object that is available on the client and the server, respectively.
>
> Nevertheless, these two constructors can be instantiated more than once, to **create multiple independent connections between different accounts servers and their clients**, in more complicated authentication situations.

Documentation: [Accounts (multi-server)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/advanced_accounts_api)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post but it doesn't seem to answer my question. Are you suggesting that if I install the `accounts-based` package as well that the user document is automatically been writing to the remote server instead of writing the user document to the local server? Because that's my problem and that's where I need help on.

Comment: This package allows you to login/logout/create user/change email/change password remotely - becouse that is the purpose of this package - any extension of `Meteor.users` is your addition, so you have to create API on your own.

Comment: Seems we talk about different things. Every collection can work with a remote app, I run several with `DDP.connect()` and the remoteURL.subscribe line. The only collection where it doesn't work is with Meteor.users. The packages I installed write the document of a new user to the client app instead of the remote app where the remoteURL.subscribe() points to. There is no need to create my own API. All collections are the same on the MongoDB. `accounts-base` is already installed

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thus I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying though, Radoslaw!